# From Objective C to Swift -class structure

Tags: swift

After years with `Objective C`, i forced my self to start the new project with `Swift`. I have read Apple's Ebook and where very impressed, although there are things i still can't do in reality .

I don't get the full pictures of the classes structure.

In `Objective C` i had this class :

```
viewController.h

@protocol BlisterViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)BlisterViewDelegateUpdatedQuantities ;

@end


@interface BlisterView : UIViewController<BlisterCellListDelegate  >
{
   int max;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) id <BlisterViewDelegate> delegate;


-(void)reloadData;
```

Then the `viewControl.m` was like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //so much stuff here

}
```

I would like to implement this with `Swift`, **where I only have 1 file**- `.swift` :

1. Where, and how you put the `@protocl` in this file- the right way ?
2. How and where you put the `@property` and the methods declarations ?
3. Where goes the "delegate registrations" `<BlisterCellListDelegate  >`
4. Same as for `viewDidLoad` and `max` ?

I am trying to get the full picture of this basic implementation .

Comment: The ebook should show you how to declare classes, protocols and variables. What swift code have you written so far?

Comment: It only show part of this, and sometimes you just don't get the picture so you ask for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything from your `.h` and `.m` files usually goes into a single .swift file (as far as their components are cohesive, which I assume they are).

Your project would look like this (all in a single .swift file):

```
import UIKit

protocol BlisterViewDelegate : class {

  func BlisterViewDelegateUpdatedQuantities()

}

class BlisterViewController : UIViewController, BlisterViewDelegate{

  var max : Int

  // MARK: - BlisterViewDelegate
  func BlisterViewDelegateUpdatedQuantities() {

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

}
```

I cannot go through all the lines and explain them to you, but if you come across something that's unclear, please let me know. If you know a bit of Swift the code should be pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: I got it all, just wanted to see the full picture to be sure, great thanks ! (although i don't remember the "!" mark from the book but i will look for it.

Comment: The `!` shouldn't be there.  In the objective-C source, the reference is to an `int` which is not an object type, therefore not a pointer, therefore can never be nil.  The appropriate translation then, is just `var max:Int`

Comment: @DavidBerry true, but that would require you to override the initializer to provide a value for max (or provide a default value) which might not be the intention here ?

Comment: An even better reason not to use an optional.  Making it non-optional requires you to think about and assign the appropriate default value.  Using `!` should be a carefully considered option (pun intended) of last resort, not something you sprinkle through code to make it compile.  If it really is optional, i.e., not always a known value, then it should require explicit unwrapping, ie., it should be `var max : Int?`

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the input. Updated the answer.

Comment: The correct translation of this from Objective-C to Swift would actually probably be more like `var max: Int = 0`.  Objective-C wouldn't allow for an optional scalar, and we're probably using storyboards, so we're never going to actually pass `max`'s value in to an initializer (init with coder would always be used from storyboard).